# How do I break down this integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> Evaluate $\int\int_R \frac{y.e^{2y}}{\sqrt{(1-x)(x-y)}}dx.dy$ where $R$ is the region of the triangle whose vertices are $(0,0), (1,0)$  and $(1,1)$.

So far, I have managed to figure out that this can be written as:
$$\int_0 ^1\int_o ^x\frac{y.e^{2y}}{\sqrt{(1-x)(x-y)}}dy.dx$$

$$\int_0 ^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}\int_o ^x\frac{y.e^{2y}}{\sqrt{x-y}}dy$$

Please tell me how do I proceed from here

Comment: May I ask where you got this question from?

Comment: @projectilemotion H.K.Dass, Introduction to Engineering Mathematics. Chapter- Double Integrals

Comment: It's better to start from $$\int^1_y\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x)(x-y)}}=\pi,$$ independent of $y$, as you can see with the substitution $$x=\frac{1+y}2+\frac{1-y}2\,t.$$

Comment: @ProfessorVector How did you came up with that substitution? That $x$ one?

Comment: I didn't come up with it, I remembered it, because I found the fact that $$\int^b_a\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(b-x)(x-a)}}=\pi$$ independent of $a,b$ rather remarkable.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Can you please prove it?

Comment: @ThedeadLegend There is probably an easier way, but Professor Vector's integral can be proven by using the First Substitution of Euler to turn the integrand into a rational function of polynomials and then finished with partial fractions.

Comment: In the general case, the substitution is $$x=\frac{a+b}2+\frac{b-a}2\,t.$$ I advise using a pencil, you won't manage to stare it down. The resulting integral will be independent of $a,b$. To calculate it, you may make still another substitution, $t=\sin\phi$, if you don't remember the derivative of $\arcsin t$.